# Add informations to listeners

Tags: java, javafx, listener, visibility

my question could sound a bit odd because i'm not sure if i can describe my problem in a easy way - but here we go:

I add to an JavaFx-Object a lot of lines and add to every line a listener - now the user will click on one of these lines and i dont know which he clicked. Is there a way to add informations to a listener?

```
public void addConnections(ICityLinker a[][]) { 
    int x1, y1, x2, y2;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            if (!(a[i][j] == null)) {
                Path path = new Path();

                x1 = map.getCountry(intToCity(i)).getX() + 5;
                y1 = map.getCountry(intToCity(i)).getY() + 5;

                MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo();
                moveTo.setX(x1);
                moveTo.setY(y1);

                x2 = map.getCountry(intToCity(j)).getX() + 5;
                y2 = map.getCountry(intToCity(j)).getY() + 5;

                LineTo lineTo = new LineTo();
                lineTo.setX(x2);
                lineTo.setY(y2);

                path.getElements().add(moveTo);
                path.getElements().add(lineTo);

                path.setStrokeWidth(2);
                path.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

                paths.add(path);

                path.getStrokeDashArray().addAll(5.0, 5.0);

                path.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                        //instead of 4 it would be helpful to have the list-position (paths is my list)
                        paths.get(4).setStroke(Color.RED);
                        paths.get(4).getStrokeDashArray().clear();
                    }

                });

                Label label = new Label();
                label.setFont(Font.font(label.getFont().getFamily(), 8));
                label.setText("" + a[i][j].getList().getFirst().getLength()
                        + " " + a[i][j].getList().getFirst().getColor());
                label.relocate((x1 + x2) / 2, (y1 + y2) / 2);
                label.idProperty().set("trackName");
                field.getChildren().addAll(path, label);
                System.out.println("linie");
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope you can help me!

MfG
baxbear

ps.: if you want you can correct my sentences - it will help me to improve my english^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to request the Source of the event? t.getSource() should return the path instance that has received the mouse event. However I didn't test it yet, so no guarantees.

```
path.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        Path p = (Path)t.getSource()
        p.setStroke(Color.RED);
        p.getStrokeDashArray().clear();
    }
});
```

In the current case you could also make the "path" variable final and use it directly in the listener:

```
final Path path = new Path();

//...

path.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        path.setStroke(Color.RED);
        path.getStrokeDashArray().clear();
    }
});
```

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: yeah it works and i really like that way to solve my problem thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :) Using `t.getSource()` is useful when you don't want to implement the EventHandler as an anonymous inner class. I tend to strip down the code in my loops as far as I can.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can do.
The first one is using the data held by the `MouseEvent` you received when an event occurs: typically, you can get the position of the mouse on the screen and try to track it back to the line you're interested in. But there might be an easier way:
Actually, you can just use any variable that is `final`. With Java8 will come the concept of *eventually final* where you won't have to care so much about it - but that's not your problem right now :)

So, basically, what you could do is declare some `final int` and initialize it to the value you're interested in before creating your `EventHandler`:

```
    final int arg = 4;

    path.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
            paths.get(arg).setStroke(Color.RED);
            paths.get(arg).getStrokeDashArray().clear();
        }

    });
```

Since you can declare a new `final int arg` at each iteration in your `for` loop, you can have a different value passed to each `Listener`. Usually, you just want to have the current value of the integer you're iterating on (in your case, `i` or `j`), so you just declare your "argument" as follows: `final int arg = i;` and you're done.

That's as simple as it gets!

Comment: hmm saw rupert's answer and i think i will do it this way instead but anyway thanks for your help

Comment: No problem :) Have fun coding!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to add one listener for the whole "collection" of lines (wrapped as a Path). Thus, the listener itself does not know which line the user clicked on.

However, you can use `getScreenX` and `getScreenY` of `MouseEvent` to obtain the coordinates the user clicked on and programatically compare them against the coordinates of the lines to find out which line the user clicked on.